# Calculate my reading speed

Tags: code-golf

*Create a program that calculates my reading speed!*

## The challenge

Write a program which takes some text as input and waits for a *start* signal from the user to display the input. When to user gives a second *end* signal, the program should output the *reading speed* of the user, which is defined as the number of words in the input divided by the time between both signals in minutes.

The word count of the input text is determined by splitting the text at white space.

### Input

- A block of text via any standard input means.
- A *start* and *end* signal by the user, either a click or pressing a certain key of your choice.

### Output

- The block of input text.
- The *reading speed* of the user as defined above.

### Rules

- The start and end signal may **not** be running and ending the program.
- The text may wrap or the user may scroll.
- The reading speed value may be returned in any of the standard methods in the meta post found [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), though the text must be displayed beforehand to the user, e.g. by printing to `stdout`.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: `the time in minutes` my guess is that most people can read this in less than a minute, so maybe seconds would work the best.

Comment: @zeppelin yeah but then the point of Words per _minute_ is ruined

Comment: It would change the calculate to words per second

Comment: All of these comments and questions are why we strongly encourage people to use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1).

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I normally do but I thought that for once I could not Sandbox something for a simple challange

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ Goes to show this is (virtually) impossible. Better now than later, though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## MATL, 24 bytes

```
O$Y.Y`OYDtDYbn60*O$Y.Z`/
```

**Explanation**

```
O$Y.    % Wait for the user's keypress
Y`      % Start the timer
        % Implicitly grab the input
OYD     % Converts control characters and creates a string
tD      % Duplicate the string and display
Ybn     % Split the string into words and count them
60*     % Multiply by 60 to convert words per second to words per minute
O$Y.    % Wait for user to press a key
Z`      % Get the elapsed time in seconds
/       % Divide the number of words (times 60) by the time in seconds
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 59 bytes

```
pause;tic;disp(x=input(''));pause;numel(strsplit(x))*60/toc
```

**Explanation**

```
pause               % Wait for a user's keypress
tic                 % Start the timer
disp(..)            % Display paragraph
pause;              % Wait for user's keypress
numel(strsplit(x))  % Determine number of words
*60                 % Multiply by 60 to convertwords per second to words per minute 
/toc                % Divide by the total time that it took (in seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Processing Js 77 bytes

```
var i="",b=second();println(i);i.split(" ");keyTyped=function(){println(i.length/(second()-b));};
```

[Try it out](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/new-program/5790491865317376)